# How to invoke method which accepts parameter of type base class using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have classes like below

```
public Class A
{    
    protected A()
    {
    }
}

Public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
    }
}
```

I have method like below

```
public class C{
    private void Method1(A obj)
    {
    }
}
```

method call using reflection

```
MethodInfo method1= typeof(C).GetMethod("Method1", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var result = method1.Invoke(cObject, new object[] { objectB });
```

I am trying to call this private method using reflection but I am getting Argument exception

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Object of type 'B' cannot be converted to type 'A'.

Could any one advise me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code looks fine to me, if you want to check the type in `Method1`, you can use `if(obj is B)` as my example

```
public class A
{    
    public A()
    {
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
    }
}

public class C
{
    private void Method1(A obj)
    {
        if (obj is B)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm B object!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm something else");
        }
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        B objectB = new B();
        A objectA = new A();
        C objectC = new C();
        
        MethodInfo method1 = typeof(C).GetMethod("Method1", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        
        method1.Invoke(objectC, new object[] { objectB });
        method1.Invoke(objectC, new object[] { objectA });
    }
}
```

Console output:

> I'm B
>
> I'm something else

Comment: No, my code errors! Its throwing argument exception

Comment: @Lamps: then the exception should be thrown somewhere else, can you copy my test code to any console project and try?

Comment: Try creating object B like A objectb = new B(). If you see my A class constructor its protected, you cant create instance in main.

Comment: @Lamps: I got the same result with `A objectB = new B();` The reason I tested with A with public `constructor` is I want to show you the output (`I'm something else`), you can keep it as `protected`.

Comment: Thank you Kienct89!! Its my mistake. Actually I had two A classes under different namespace. And I was using the wrong one and hence the problem. :(

Comment: @Lamps: we all make silly mistakes :). Glad you figured it out yourself, I did not help much.